# Spring data neo4j embedded property MappingException

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am fairly new to Neo4J; I am developing a project for learning purposes on which I am facing an issue that I am not managing to solve. My model might be somewhat relational DB influenced, but design issues aside, I believe however that what I am attempting should technically be done.

I have a `NodeEntity` `Foo` with an nested object `Bar`, converted to- and from `String` via `ConversionService`. In effect, `Bar` contains only one single `String` field, making the mapping trivial.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Foo {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    @Indexed
    private Bar bar;
    ...
}

public class Bar {
    private String value;
    ... 
}
```

When returning from a fairly simple Cypher query defined as follows on my repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(...)
public interface FooRepository
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Foo, Long> {
    ...
    @Query ("MATCH (foo) RETURN foo.bar")
    Iterable<Bar> listBars ();
    ...
}
```

Conversion is configured as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = "de.h7r.playground.sd.neo4j",
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter({ Configuration.class }))
public class PKanbanConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionService ()
            throws Exception {

        final ConversionServiceFactoryBean csfb = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean ();
        csfb.setConverters (getConverters ());

        return csfb;
    }

    private Set<Converter> getConverters () {
        return Sets.newHashSet (new BarConverter.ToString (), new BarConverter.FromString ());
    }
}
```

Where the code for BarConverter is as follows.

```
public class BarConverter {

    public static class FromString <S extends String, P extends Bar>
            implements Converter<S, P> {

        @Override
        public P convert (final S source) {
           // sets value into new instance of Bar and returns
        }
    }

    public static class ToString <P extends Bar, S extends String>
            implements Converter<P, S> {

        @Override
        public S convert (final P source) {
            // gets value from Bar and returns
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception.

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Unknown persistent entity test.domain.Bar
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:178)
...
```

`Bar` is indeed not a persitent entity nor should in my understanding be one. I grasp that this might have something to do with the defined return type of `listBars`; on the other hand, the repository if of `Foo`s, so I had expected it to work. I would very much *not* like to fetch the whole set of nodes and then filter only the nested objects; the same way I would not like to have `Bar` replaced by `String` on `Foo`, since their type might have semantic relevance.

I am a bit lost as to how to returning all the property values for the existing nodes, specially since this query works as expected from neo4j-shell, so I see this as a pure Spring mapping issue.

I can add any further information that might prove helpful upon request.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: How did you configure the conversion service?

Comment: @remigio Edited question to include requested information.

Comment: The converters are correctly defined, seems that the configuration is not working, I'm not a Spring expert so I can't help you with configuration matters. I successfully configured converters using the XML configuration.